# I was getting output of exec.Command output in the following manner. from that output I want to get data which I needed

Tags: json, go, exec, stdout

Here from output I want only json data with requestStatus Failed part only. remaining json data should be override each update/can be deleted. could you pls suggest me how can I get data which is only required.
source Code: my source code looks like this.

```
cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)
cmd.Dir = dir

var stdBuffer bytes.Buffer
mw := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, &stdBuffer)

cmd.Stdout = mw
cmd.Stderr = mw

// Execute the command
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Panic(err)
}

log.Println(stdBuffer.String())

    
Output: this is how output looks for my input.

{
   "time": "10:26:03 AM",
   "requestId": 71795,
   "requestStatus": "ongoing",
   "requestMessage": "Waiting for response"
}
{
   "time": "10:26:08 AM",
   "requestId": 71795,
   "requestStatus": "ongoing",
   "requestMessage": "Waiting for response"
}
{
   "time": "10:26:13 AM",
   "requestId": 71795,
   "requestStatus": "ongoing",
   "requestMessage": "Waiting for response"
}
{
   "time": "10:26:14 AM",
   "requestId": 71795,
   "requestStatus": "failed",
   "requestMessage": {
      "ValidationResult": {
         "logs": {
            "Elements": null,
            "objectsErrors": null,
            "occurrencesErrors": null
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: The output is a series of JSON objects. Unmarshal a series of JSON objects from it. What have you tried? What problems do you have? Or is this the output of serveral runs? Then the output may be just a single JSON object.

Comment: This output is for single run only. I just executed command once and then I got response like that from peer. in that output json object which is at last (request status Failed) is the valid output from peer. I tried to unmarshal the received output i got error like unmarshal failed 'invalid character '{' is received'

Comment: invalid character '{' after top-level value"}

Comment: can I get help from anyone for this issue.

Comment: I posted an answer which works for me. Try it and if it doesn't work for you, please explain why, and describe what you get.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to unmarshal something that contains multiple (independent) JSON values, such as your output (which is a concatenation of multiple JSON objects).

Use [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to decode multiple JSON values (objects) from a stream one-by-one.

For example:

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(output))

var m map[string]interface{}
for {
    if err := dec.Decode(&m); err != nil {
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Decoded:", m)
}
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/PJ2EXliiXkS)):

```
Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:Waiting for response requestStatus:ongoing time:10:26:03 AM]
Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:Waiting for response requestStatus:ongoing time:10:26:08 AM]
Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:Waiting for response requestStatus:ongoing time:10:26:13 AM]
Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:map[ValidationResult:map[logs:map[Elements:<nil> objectsErrors:<nil> occurrencesErrors:<nil>]]] requestStatus:failed time:10:26:14 AM]
```

To decode content from your `stdBuffer`, you may pass that to [`json.NewDecoder()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#NewDecoder):

```
dec := json.NewDecoder(&stdBuffer)
```

If you only need to output the object with `"failed"` status, simply use an `if` statement:

```
    if m["requestStatus"] == "failed" {
        fmt.Println("Decoded:", m)
    }
```

This will only output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/YiMoQsB-c15)):

```
Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:map[ValidationResult:map[logs:map[Elements:<nil> objectsErrors:<nil> occurrencesErrors:<nil>]]] requestStatus:failed time:10:26:14 AM]
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I was getting same output what you have shared. But I wanted only this following output from that series. Decoded: map[requestId:71795 requestMessage:map[ValidationResult:map[logs:map[Elements:<nil> objectsErrors:<nil> occurrencesErrors:<nil>]]] requestStatus:failed time:10:26:14 AM]

Comment: @Raghavendra 99% of the solution is handed to you. Please think a little. I updated the answer to output only the failed status.