# unmarshal json file with multiple json object (not valid json file)

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have a json file (file.json) with following content:

file.json:

```
{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}
```

The contents of the file are exactly as above (not valid json file)

I want use data in my code but I can not Unmarshal This

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read string line by line and unmarshal it:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

type j struct {
    Job string `json:"job"`
}

func main() {
    payload := strings.NewReader(`{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}`)
    fscanner := bufio.NewScanner(payload)
    for fscanner.Scan() {
        var job j
        err := json.Unmarshal(fscanner.Bytes(), &job)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("%s", err)
            continue
        }
        fmt.Printf("JOB %+v\n", job)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
JOB {Job:developer}
JOB {Job:taxi driver}
JOB {Job:police}
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/XbXi4aeZF9N)

Comment: That's fragile as it hinges on the two facts: 1) there will ever be no differently-formatted JSON object which would have a line break as part of any whitespace block; 2) there will ever be no line break embedded in a string literal containing in a JSON object. Hence I'm with @icza on this.

Comment: This also breaks if a single line contains multiple JSON objects.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is not a single JSON object but a series of (unrelated) JSON objects. You can't use [`json.Unmarshal()`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) to unmarshal something that contains multiple (independent) JSON values.

Use [`json.Decoder`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Decoder) to decode multiple JSON values (objects) from a source one-by-one.

For example:

```
func main() {
    f := strings.NewReader(file)
    dec := json.NewDecoder(f)

    for {
        var job struct {
            Job string `json:"job"`
        }
        if err := dec.Decode(&job); err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break
            }
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Decoded: %+v\n", job)
    }
}

const file = `{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}`
```

Which outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ytw3lQKU5R_4)):

```
Decoded: {Job:developer}
Decoded: {Job:taxi driver}
Decoded: {Job:police}
```

This solution works even if your JSON objects take up multiple lines in the source file, or if there are multiple JSON objects in the same line.

See related: [I was getting output of exec.Command output in the following manner. from that output I want to get data which I needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443414/i-was-getting-output-of-exec-command-output-in-the-following-manner-from-that-o/64443733#64443733)